# Como puedo pasar un FormData por el metodo PUT O UPDATE en API fetch de javascrip?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy intentando hacer una peticion por el metodo PUT pero al intentar enviar la FormData se envia vacio tal vez necesite algun tipo de encanbezado o necesito enviarlo como json o text alguien me podrá ayudar?

```
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // construyo mi formData con el evento currentTarget
  const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
  
  // El tipo de metodo lo obtengo del valor de un boton
  const btnSubmit = formClientAdd.querySelector(".sendDataBtn")

  const method = {
    insert: 'POST',
    update: 'PUT'
  }

  // Envió la informacion pero al recibirla en el backend llega sin nada
  fetch(URL, {
    method: method[btnSubmit.value],
    body: formData
  }).then(
   response => response.json()
  ).then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```

Estoy usando la libreria Flightphp y asi recibo la request

```
  // Recibiendo los datos de la request
  $request = Flight::request()->data;
  $files = Flight::request()->files->cliente_ine;

  // Devolviendo respuesta
  Flight::json($request);
```

Sin embargo al obtener la response regresa [] no se que esta pasando solo me pasa con los metodos mencionados